# Firebase Firestore GetInstance Failing on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to obtain an instance of Firebase Firestore on Android.This line of code below fails repeatedly.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

It throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` with the error

```
FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null
at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have enabled Firestore on the console, I have used Firebase Assistant to ensure Android Studio project is synched up correctly with the console project. Other Firebase components that I am using such as Real-time Database, Authentication, Storage, etc works except Firestore.

I have added the dependency `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried manually downloading the google-services.json file from the console and placing it in your project?

Comment: @DougStevenson is right.  Make sure you have a recent `google-services.json` file and are using `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0` or higher (not `3.0.0`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The project ID is read from the `google-services.json` file.

Make sure you have a recent `google-services.json` file and are using `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0` or higher (not `3.0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'`
That's that latest currently. Please check your firebase console for the most recent version

Answer (score 0):

```
changing the project gradle google services worked for me thanks

just by adding in the project gradle, under dependencies
```

dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy project_id from google-services.json to string.xml then it works fine.